# How to Convert Paragraph(string) to line (array) in PHP?

Tags: php

I have paragraph like this.

```
Rose Helen (b. 13 May 1937), married The Lord Luce.Laura Violet (b. 18 January 1939), married Sir John Montgomery-Cuninghame of Corsehill, 12th Baronet. Emma Harriet (b. 16 October 1941), married Sir Michael Harris Caine.Harriet Mary (b. 29 June 1946), married Charles Hugh Flower (a maternal great-great-grandson of the 1st Duke of Abercorn). As Nicholson had no sons from his marriage, his title became extinct upon his death in 1991.
```

I  want to convert paragraph(string) into line(array) like this

```
1.Rose Helen (b. 13 May 1937), married The Lord Luce.
2.Laura Violet (b. 18 January 1939), married Sir John Montgomery-Cuninghame of Corsehill, 12th Baronet.
3.Emma Harriet (b. 16 October 1941), married Sir Michael Harris Caine.
4.Harriet Mary (b. 29 June 1946), married Charles Hugh Flower (a maternal great-great-grandson of the 1st Duke of Abercorn).
5.As Nicholson had no sons from his marriage, his title became extinct upon his death in 1991.
```

So i create code like this

```
 <?PHP

$para="Rose Helen (b. 13 May 1937), married The Lord Luce.Laura Violet (b. 18 January 1939), married Sir John Montgomery-Cuninghame of Corsehill, 12th Baronet.Emma Harriet (b. 16 October 1941), married Sir Michael Harris Caine.Harriet Mary (b. 29 June 1946), married Charles Hugh Flower (a maternal great-great-grandson of the 1st Duke of Abercorn).As Nicholson had no sons from his marriage, his title became extinct upon his death in 1991.";


$line = explode(". ",$para);

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($line); ++$i) {

  echo "<P>$i.$line[$i]</P>";

  }
?>
```

it works without error but it give the output like this

```
0.Rose Helen (b

1.13 May 1937), married The Lord Luce.Laura Violet (b

2.18 January 1939), married Sir John Montgomery-Cuninghame of Corsehill, 12th Baronet.Emma Harriet (b

3.16 October 1941), married Sir Michael Harris Caine.Harriet Mary (b

4.29 June 1946), married Charles Hugh Flower (a maternal great-great-grandson of the 1st Duke of Abercorn).As Nicholson had no sons from his marriage, his title became extinct upon his death in 1991.
```

I want the output as each sentence as new line.here because the `b. 13 may 1937`
the php take it as new line so plz give any idea or suggestion that i can convert the paragraph into line ignoring `b. 13 May 1937` type of hurdle.
plz help me.

Comment: *sentence as **new line*** So why don't you split on a new line?

Comment: sorry it is my mistake it is continous line with out line break...now i edit it and correct it

Comment: You don't have a space after the `.` at the end of the senteces.

Comment: But you DO have a space after the `.` in `(b. 13 May 1937)`. So `explode` is splitting it up at those dates.

Comment: yes they  have space.i try "." and ". " .nothing works

Comment: NO, they don't. It says `Luce.Laura` with no space around the `.`

Comment: I guess you need to parse the string, word by word.

Comment: Regular expression is the way to go. But the last line of the expected final output makes constructing such a regular expression especially difficult, since it takes away the apparent order present in the previous lines.

Comment: can you provide or any links or example?? for regular expression

Comment: Well, here you go: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: Since paragraphs have no space after the dot, you could use preg_split instead of explode... you could get a regex that replaces all (and only) dots NOT followed by a space.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `preg_split` function like as

```
$result = preg_split('/\.+(?![^\(]*\))/',$str);
print_r(array_filter($result));
```

**Explanation(Regex) :**

```
\.+(?![^\(]*\))
```

- `\.+` matches the character `.` literally
- `(?![^\(]*\))` Negative Lookahead - Not to match those characters that comes within `() parentheses`

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/446932)

Comment: Man You are Genius.You saved my Life.God Bless You.God Give you all happiness in your life

Comment: it works with only () how to works with all kind like Dr. etc

Comment: i want to use this for universal use where paragraph convert into line ignoring this type of mistake,

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution, using regular expression:

```
$para="Rose Helen (b. 13 May 1937), married The Lord Luce.Laura Violet (b. 18 January 1939), married Sir John Montgomery-Cuninghame of Corsehill, 12th Baronet.Emma Harriet (b. 16 October 1941), married Sir Michael Harris Caine.Harriet Mary (b. 29 June 1946), married Charles Hugh Flower (a maternal great-great-grandson of the 1st Duke of Abercorn).As Nicholson had no sons from his marriage, his title became extinct upon his death in 1991.";
$split_arr = preg_split("/\.[a-zA-Z]+ /", $para);
var_dump($split_arr);
```

Basically, the regular expression says to split the string at:

> 1. A literal "." (dot), then:
> 2. One or more alphabets, (This elemintates the possibility of having strings like beginning with something like "(b. 13 May..." in the array. Then:
> 3. A space character

So, based on your code, you should have:

```
$line =  preg_split("/\.[a-zA-Z]+ /", $para);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($line); ++$i) {
   echo "<P>$i.$line[$i]</P>";
}
```